# How to check which router condition is working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am working on an existing project but here is problem. In `router.php` there are 200+ redirections and I want to know which redirection is working right now on a specific page - is there any way to know that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question. I always try to use the magic routing for simplicity in this because it always seems such a pain to track routes manually back through the many redirections in a routing file that any part way complex site will have, especial with regex routings. Debugging a problematic routing can be a real pain. Would also love an answer to this question. I searched the CI forums when I read your question and googled but found nothing of relevance to CI3 or in reference to it so I am assuming it is impossible, very difficult or problematic at best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any native way in Codeigniter to spit it out, like with knowing which database is being used for example:

```
echo $this->db->database;
```

But if you were to check your URL and note the first URI segment, which you could also get by echoing this:

```
echo $this->uri->segment(1);
```

That at least gives you which bit to look for in the routes.php file.

I haven't seen one with 200+ routes though so not sure what kind of mess you may be reviewing.